# uiwebpage does not load

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a basic webpage but it does not load. Its a bit weird ..

I have this code (this does not work )

```
    NSString *test = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
    NSLog(@" %@",test); // returns http://westminsteriphone.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/another-blog-post/
[itemSummary loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:test]]];
```

But if i try ..

```
[itemSummary loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://westminsteriphone.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/another-blog-post/"]];
```

it works .. :S why doesnt the first example load up

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NSString *test = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
    NSLog(@" %@",test); // returns http://westminsteriphone.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/another-blog-post/
[itemSummary loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text]]]];
```

Comment: ddi you try to debug with breakbpoints on the loadRequest row?? if not check what kind of value test has when it tries to load a Request

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[itemSummary loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"link"]]]]];
```

if u use those two lines in different function then do like this

```
 function 1

 NSString *test = [[NSString alloc]init];

 test =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"link"]];


 return [test autorelease];



 function 2



 [itemSummary loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:test]]];
```